# How can I set the dropdown value based on class on a visible element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I have a series of divs that hide/show based on some of the other page content. What I want now is for a dropdown to be preselected based on which one of these divs is visible.
.foo has 3 classes total, and the third class is the one that matches the possible values in my dropdown. The code I put together from some other Stack Overflow answers works fine to select a value in the dropdown, but it's always picking the first div with .foo regardless if it is hidden or not.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   var $allClasses = $(".foo").attr('class').split(' ');
   for(var i=0; i < $allClasses.length; i++) {

   var selected = $allClasses[2];
   $("#bar").val( selected );    
 }

});
```

I have tried adding :visible to .foo when setting the $allClasses variable but it just returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined".

Thanks!

Edit:

Sorry for not including this before!
So I'm actually populating the html from a WordPress loop, and the one that shows is based on another dropdown on the website but I'm not having any issues with that. Accidentally called them divs but they're actually headings.

The query loops through the posts and creates a heading for each post that looks roughly like this:

```html
<h3 class="foo second targetvalue1" style="display:none">My Heading 1</h3>
<h3 class="foo second targetvalue2" style="display:none">My Heading 2</h3>
<h3 class="foo second targetvalue3" style="display:none">My Heading 3</h3>
```

They all start with display:none, and I have some javascript that makes it visible based on a cookie value (works fine).

Then this is the code for the dropdown. This is also populated from a WordPress loop but the html itself looks like this:

```html
<select name="bar" id="bar">
    <option disabled selected value="noselection">Select an option</option>
    <option value="targetvalue1">Target Value 1</option>
    <option value="targetvalue2">Target Value 2</option>
    <option value="targetvalue3">Target Value 3</option>
</select>
```

So say the heading that is currently visible is the one with the class targetvalue2, then it should automatically select Target Value 2 from the dropdown.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your question.

Comment: most likely you need .each() for this. but need to see the HTML structure to give an exact answer

Comment: Sorry! I have edited my question to include the html.

Comment: @DaniB, using same cookie value to set dropdown would make it easy and simply, can you provide cookie parameter which makes h3 visible

Comment: I wish I could do it like that, but unfortunately this dropdown has a different set of options than the cookie which is why I didn't include it. The way I mentioned the cookie was a bit misleading I suppose, sorry about that!

Comment: @DaniB have you tried my solution ? You just have to copy paste my code after you show one of the `foo` element and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks @tcj, sorry for the wait. I'm still getting the same error but I've run into some other issues with my code so I think there's something else on my end that I need to fix. Your solution works when I set up my dropdown manually so I've accepted it as the correct answer. Cheers!

Comment: In case anyone ever finds this and has a burning desire to know how I fixed my issue, it was returning as undefined because in my case it was trying to set the dropdown when the page was ready, the same time the other js I wrote was trying to select the correct one to display. I added a very slight delay to the accepted answer and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, basically, you select the `foo` class which has a style different to `display:none;` (using jquery's [not equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)), this allows you to select the class which is not hidden so then you can fetch its name to make it selected by default :

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var displayedElement = $('.foo[style!="display:none"]').attr('class').split(' ');
    var classToSelect = displayedElement[2];   
    $("#bar").val( classToSelect );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="foo second targetvalue1" style="display:none">My Heading 1</h3>
<h3 class="foo second targetvalue2" style="display:block">My Heading 2</h3>
<h3 class="foo second targetvalue3" style="display:none">My Heading 3</h3>

<select name="bar" id="bar">
    <option disabled selected value="noselection">Select an option</option>
    <option value="targetvalue1">Target Value 1</option>
    <option value="targetvalue2">Target Value 2</option>
    <option value="targetvalue3">Target Value 3</option>
</select>
```